# setContentView fragment not visible

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

In my app I'm trying to change the background color of a LinearLayout when the fragment is visible. This works fine when I don't change the layout with a `setContentView()`. I want to show a ListView when something happens so I show that with `setContentView()`, after the items have been selected I use `setContentView()` to set the layout back to the main layout but for some reason fragment.isVisible returns false. This is the code:

```
 private void setFeedback(int color) {
        Log.d(TAG, "set background color to:" + color + " mmainfragment is " + mMainFragment + mMainFragment.isAdded() + mMainFragment.isHidden() + mMainFragment.isVisible());
        if (mMainFragment != null && mMainFragment.isVisible()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "****COLOR ON THE SCREEN");
            mMainFragment.mLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
            mFeedbackTask = new FeedbackTask();
            mFeedbackTask.execute();
        }
    }
```

It logs the following on start:

> set background color to:-3407872 mmainfragment is MainFragment{41c30588 #0 id=0x7f07003c}true false true

Then I use setContentView to the ListView as follows:

```
setContentView(R.layout.feedback_popup);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.feedback_list, feedback.getOptions());
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.feedback_screen);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And back to the main  view as follows:

```
setContentView(R.layout.overview);
```

Then when I try again it logs this:

> set background color to:-3407872 mmainfragment is MainFragment{41c30588 #0 id=0x7f07003c}true false false

Why is it not visible if both isAdded() and isHidden() return true and false respectively?

Comment: It is strange that you setContentView 2 times. I guess when you set this again, it will be re-rendered. If you have 2 layouts, why don't you divide into 2 fragments?

Comment: That worked thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason setContentView doesn't work the way I hoped, fixed it by using fragments.